# Infinite loop over text large text file

Tags: bash, file, loops, logging, infinite

I'm trying to clean out a large log file. The first couple words in each file is the the date in mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss. If this entry is more than six months past the current date, I want to delete it from the file. Currently I am infinitely looping over this huge text file. Also, the program should stop looping over lines as soon as it finds a date within six months of the current date. Any help would be great. I dont think the loop is getting the next line.

P.S. i'm not great with bash.

```
#!/bin/bash

sixmonths=15552000

infile=/home/user/Desktop/testfile1.log

currentDate=$(date +%s)

count=-1

#for line in $infile
while IFS= read -r line; do
        #count=`expr $count + 1`        
        logDate=($line:0:19)
        logDate=$(date --date="$logDate" +%s)
        diff=`expr $currentDate - $logDate`

        if [[ $diff -gt $sixmonths ]] then
                count=`expr $count + 1`
                echo $count
                #sed -i '$countD' $infile
                #echo deleting line
                #sed -i '$line/d' ./$infile

        else
                echo STOPPING PROGRAM DONE!!!!!!!!!!!!
                exit
        fi

done < $infile

sed -i '0,$countd' $infile
```

Comment: You're doing good enough for a bash beginner, but you need to think about framing your Q better. Please add sample data with 1 "record" that is more than 6 months old, and 1 record that is current. If the data is multi-line, we need to know that, but we don't needed a 40,000 char wide line to  understand or help solve  your problem, just the relevant bits from that line that help you know "keep or delete". You might want to look at [Awk Tutorial](http://grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html) as it will be a much better tool to learn if you're going to be processing text alot. ....

Comment: As far as improving your bash skills, the first place to start is fix any stuff flagged by pasting your code in at https://shellcheck.net . Good luck!

Comment: Don't use backticks - use `$()` instead. Don't use `expr` - use shell math (for integers) instead: `diff=$((currentDate - logDate))` or in Bash `(( diff = currentDate - logDate ))`. `(( count++ ))` is another example. Use Bash integer comparisons: `if (( diff > sixmonths ))`. This syntax is incorrect: `logDate=($line:0:19)` - this is what you need: `logDate=${line:0:19}`. Instead of running `sed` many times in a loop, you're already reading the file, just output each line that you want to keep into a new file and skip the lines that you want to "delete": `echo "$line" >> "$outputfile"`. Or ...

Comment: ...if you use your count, fix your final `sed` command: `sed -i "0,${count}d" "$infile"`. Quote your variables!